# Will SAPI work on android?

Tags: android, c++, sapi

I am thinking about adding SAPI to cocos2dx, but am unsure if it will run on android.

Should I go with it or use google speech api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use google speech api, since you want to use for android. Google speech api has really nice results.